# Solr - Password with Special Character in SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD throw keystore password was incorrect

Tags: ssl, solr, ssl-certificate, keystore, keystore-access

When setting up SSL for Solr (in windows OS), keystore password with special characters throws "keystore password was incorrect" error.

Sample Password: 7V4StJ!Qc%8V

1. Is there any rule on having special characters in the password for
   Solr keystore?
2. Should password start with alpha characters?
3. If I add password with single quotes in Solr.in.cmd, I am still getting
   error. SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD='7V4StJ!Qc%8V'

How should I handle this?

Comment: My guess is that since `%` has special meaning in cmd scripts, in particular `%8` which is used to refer to "the eight parameter given to the command". To escape it and get a single percent sign, use two: `%%`

Comment: It did not help. I tried to escape the characters by refering the link (https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) but it was again throwing wrong key store password.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix it by keeping the password with special character in a separate file (single line file) and while setting the variable in batch file, I am reading it from the file and setting it up. It worked.

```
set /p SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=<key
```

where key is the file with the password in single line. Check the arrow (<) near the file name.